# WPF Set SelectedValue for ComboBox on page reload

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

I have a ComboBox that is created when the page is initialised

```
 Dim CategoryCombo As New CustomControl.ComboCBx
        With CategoryCombo
            .Name = "MaintTypes_CatCombo"
        End With
        RegisterControl(MaintenanceTypes_Grid, CategoryCombo)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(CategoryCombo)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(TS_Separator)
```

and added to the toolbar

It is populated in the load event

```
Dim CatCombo As CustomControl.ComboCBx = MaintenanceTypes_Grid.FindName("MaintTypes_CatCombo")
 With CatCombo
            .IsNewRecord = False
            .Width = 200
            .ItemsSource = ReturnCategories.DefaultView
            .SelectedValuePath = "ID"
            .DisplayMemberPath = "Name"
            .SelectedIndex = 0

        End With
```

If the user navigates to another page and returns the selected value is returned to the selected index of 0. I can grab the last selected value before leaving the page but cannot find a way to set .SelectedValue when the page reloads

Data comes from

```
Private Function ReturnCategories() As DataTable
    Try
        CatDT = New DataTable
        With CatDT.Columns
            .Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
        End With
        With CatDT.Rows
            .Add(0, "Select Category")
        End With
        Using vService As New Service1Client
            strSQL = "SELECT Category_ID as 'ID', Category_Name as 'Name' FROM Maintenance_Categories "
            strSQL += "WHERE Management_ID = " & Management_ID
            strSQL += " ORDER BY Category_Name"
            Dim DS As DataSet = vService.ReturnDataSetHAS(strSQL)
            For Each Row As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows
                With CatDT.Rows
                    .Add(Row("ID"), ReturnText(Row("Name")))
                End With
            Next
        End Using
        Return CatDT
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround  - return the index from the DataTable and set the .SelectedIndex of the ComboBox with that

In case someone has deleted the selected item prior to returning to the page check the row exists first

```
 Dim vIndex As Integer = 0
        If Not CurrentCategory = 0 Then
            Dim vRow As DataRow = CatDT.Select("ID = '" & CurrentCategory & "'").FirstOrDefault()
            If Not vRow Is Nothing Then
                vIndex = CatDT.Rows.IndexOf(vRow)
            End If
        End If
        With CatCombo
            .IsNewRecord = False
            .Width = 200
            .ItemsSource = ReturnCategories.DefaultView
            .SelectedValuePath = "ID"
            .DisplayMemberPath = "Name"
            .SelectedIndex = vIndex
        End With
```